How to capture all error messages using NamedParameterJdbcTemplate batchUpdate with Mysql
I am using the  NamedParameterJdbcTemplate batchUpdate in my application using Mysql as database. While any exception occurs I am catching it through DataAccessException and I can get all the update counts, but unable to find out all the error messages. Rather I am getting the only last exception occurred.
Ex. I am getting 10 types of exceptions in my batch operation. I am getting the last exception only in exception stack.
How to get all the database exceptions/error messages properly?
Want to get all the error messages properly in exception stack.

To capture error messages during a batchUpdate using NamedParameterJdbcTemplate in Spring, you can use a try-catch block to handle DataAccessException, which is thrown for database-related issues. In the catch block, log the exception message and stack trace to capture the error. If you want to capture errors for individual items in the batch, iterate over the data list and execute individual updates in a separate try-catch block. This ensures that if some records fail, you can log the specific error messages while still processing the remaining records.

Thanks for your reponse. But I am using -try{
namedParameterJdbcTemplate.batchUpdate(,
sqlParamSourceList.toArray(new SqlParameterSource[0]));
}
catch (DataAccessException e) {
} // But here I am only getting the last exception caught but want to capture  all errors/exceptions occurred.
